# In Realm DB Updating a value in an array at a particular index not working?

Tags: android, realm

I am trying to change a `RealmResults` array value at a particular `index`, my code is given below but when I am trying to `setInc()` it is not incrementing in `Realm DB`.

```
story = realm.where(storydata.class).findAll();
story.get(0).setInc("545454"); // Here Inc field value is not changing in Realm DB.
```

Can anyone please tell me why is this happening.

Comment: Do you do this in a write transaction? `executeTransaction()` or `beginTransaction()/commitTransaction()`

Comment: In `executeTransactionAsync`

Comment: Well, it *should* work, then. Once the transaction commits (so it ran without errors)